# FileSystemWatcher OnOpened event

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

In .Net how can I monitor if a file has been accessed (opened) by other programs? I can't see OnOpened event in FileSystemWatcher, so I assume it can not do that. Is there any other way to do it? It's clearly possible in Windows, is there some sort of hook available from .Net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the NotifyFilters property.  You probably want to look for changes in access date/time.

Comment: Will it raise OnChanged event then?

Comment: @HeavyWave Yes, it will raise the OnChange event.  Check out the ChangeType property of the FileSystemEventArgs to determine WHAT changed - if that is important to you.

Answer (score 2):

NotifyFilters enumeration has interesting you value: LastAccess indicating last file or directory access. This has to be set to the NotifyFilter property.